# <Error>: -[__NSDictionaryI WLJSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1740f9d80

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Trying to deploy a mobilefirst project using testflight and the app stop after the error.

: -[__NSDictionaryI WLJSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1740f9d80

The app works when deployed using xCode, but when installed form TestFlight, it shows black screen with the error when inspecting device log.

Comment: Specify the version and build id of MFP on which you are facing the issue.

Comment: MFP 7.1.0.00.20151023-1449

Comment: What is the app doing when the crash is happening?

Comment: Basically, the app start to initialize and load the worklight.plist file. I see the debug shows the worklight.plist values and then it crash with the above message. Again, this works directly deploying the app by xcode but when achieving with xcode, the ipa or the test flight deployment doesnt work. Finally, i recreated a brand new project with mfp 7.1 command line and added all the files from the old app and i dont have the problem. I still didint figureout whey the upgraded app was crashing while looking for the NSDictionary extension provided by the worklight library.

Comment: Sounds like an upgrade error. Do you want to keep this question open, or delete it and bring it back if the issue re-surfaces?

Comment: Yes. It happened on upgrade only. I would like to keep this question opened if anyone else get into the same situation.

Comment: Facing Same issue, Tried version 7.1 of worklight. Not much support from IBM. If anybody have a sample project which get execute successfully please post the link.

Comment: Abhi, Instead of upgrade, i created a new project using mfp create project name using mfp 7.1 and added our files from older version of worklight. I couldnt find any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved similar problem by following Steps in following link.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/configuring-a-native-ios-application-with-the-mfp-sdk/

Mainly, I was able to reproduce this by removing

> -ObjC.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like an upgrade error. However without providing a sample project to recreate the error and debug it, there is not much to do other than creating a new application and migrate the app source into it.

Comment: I am facing this issue in MFPF 7.1. Project is really basic iOS app with one line of coded added [[WLClient sharedInstance] wlConnectWithDelegate:myConnectListener]; Is this issue resolved?